# Symfony: how to display a success message after logout

Tags: php, symfony, logout

In Symfony, after a user successfully log out, how to display a success message like "you have successfully logged out" ?

Comment: that was a fast answer of yourself :)

Comment: I've just spent a bit of time to figure out the simplest way to accomplish this, then I thought it was worthy to share :D

Comment: Thanks dude, you could add it in stack overflow documentation too :]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Create a new service to handle the logout success event.

In `services.yml` add the service:

```
logout_success_handler:
    class: Path\To\YourBundle\Services\LogoutSuccessHandler
    arguments: ['@security.http_utils']
```

And add the class, replacing `/path/to/your/login` with the url of your login page (in the last line of the controller):

```
<?php

namespace Path\To\YourBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface;

class LogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    protected $httpUtils;
    protected $targetUrl;

    /**
     * @param HttpUtils $httpUtils
     */
    public function __construct(HttpUtils $httpUtils)
    {
        $this->httpUtils = $httpUtils;

        $this->targetUrl = '/path/to/your/login?logout=success';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        $response = $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->targetUrl);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

2) Configure your `security.yml` to use the custom `LogoutSuccessHandler` just created:

```
firewalls:
    # ...
    your_firewall:
        # ...
        logout:
            # ...
            success_handler: logout_success_handler
```

3) In the twig template of your login page add:

```
{% if app.request.get('logout') == "success" %}
    <p>You have successfully logged out!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 6):

Imho, there is a definitively simpler way. In `security.yaml`, define a route to redirect to after logout thanks to the `target` key :

```
security:
  firewalls:
    main:
     [...]
     logout:
       path: /logout
       target: /logout_message
```

Then in a controller (`SecurityController.php` is fine for this), define this action, wich only add the flash message and then redirect where you want (home in this exemple) :

```
/**
 * @Route("/logout_message", name="logout_message")
 */
public function logoutMessage()
{
    $this->addFlash('success', "You've been disconnected. Bye bye !");
    return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
}
```

Comment: That's the best solution IMO if you want to show a truly *flash* message :)