# Symfony 4 : Display flashbag after logout

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have this website where users have to pass a test, at the end they have access to the test results. They can be send by mail and this will send an email, delete the records from the database, disconnect the user and redirect him to the login page.

Once disconnected and redirected to the login page, I want to display a confirmation message like "Thanks for your participation ! Your results have just been sent by email ".

This is what I wrote in my function, inside my controller:

```php
$request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Thanks for your participation ! ...');

return $this->redirectToRoute('app_logout');
```

And this is what I wrote in my view (login_page)

```
{% for message in app.flashes('success') %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried this without disconnecting the user and that works! 
But once I use the route 'app_logout', this is impossible to display the flashbag, because the user's session is inaccessible.
I don't know what to do yet, to sum up, this is my direction:

(VIEW) Display tests results-> (CONTROLLER) function that send mail / add the flashbag / redirect to app_logout ->(?) app_logout disconnect user & redirige to-> (VIEW) Login page where I want to display my flashbag

Does anyone have an idea of ​​what can be done?

Comment: @MichalS. What do you mean by that?

Comment: IMO answer for your question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062805/symfony-how-to-display-a-success-message-after-logout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony: how to display a success message after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062805/symfony-how-to-display-a-success-message-after-logout)

Comment: @MichalS. Thanks you, the solutions that both present are really interesting! Do you think I can adapt that to my problem? Because I do not want to display a message everytime an user logout, but only when I disconnect an user after sending him a mail

Comment: of course - simply define conditions in your own handler :) probably you will have to write some service which will check this scenario and "voilà"!

Comment: @MichalS. Ok so I did something similar to the other post, my condition was to check the HTTP_REFERER , if it comes from the page that sent the mail the message will be displayed. But the problem is, when the user don't choose the sent the mail and logout by itself, the message is displayed. An other solution (which is not the best) is to add a column "mailSent" in my User's entity (0 = no mail / 1 = mail sent), like this my function could check and display the related message "mail sent " or "you've been disconnected". I wanted to try to set up a service but i have no idea where to start

Comment: I'd store the information about sent email in database and check from there if mail has been sent. IMO User entity is not a good place for this (but I don't know your business requirement / use case).

Comment: @MichalS. I don't have any specific requirement, should I create a new entity mail relate to User entity ? The columns would be : id, user_id, date                              So my condition would be like if (email exists and date < 10 minutes ) -> display message. What do you think about that?

Comment: IMO - Yes this is a good way. Every entity should be as single as possible - user should not be aware of any email sent. Please imagine what would you do if you would like to check if another type of email has been sent? You probably will add another column (field in entity) called something like "email2" what sounds like a future nightmare. When you create special entity for this purpose, you can add as many types of emails as you want.

Comment: Thanks you for all those tips ! I still have a problem with my message, how can the function logout check if the right email is sent if the function do not know the user id ?

Comment: I'd store in cookie (there are many places where you can store this data for example in some cache (redis?)) last logged id and then you can in your own handler get last logged user id from there.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution would probably be a custom [Logout Success Listener](https://chrisguitarguy.com/2019/08/06/symfony-logout-handlers-vs-logout-success-handlers/), which checks the email sent information in the database and sets the flashbag for the fresh session if applicable.

Comment: Thanks ! But I still have the same problem, how can the logout know the user id ? In order to check if the right email has been sent